# SIP Connection in SE Plateform

Tags: java, sip

There are documents on SIP connections with J2ME. I want to know how to create a SIP connection and do REGISTER and send messages in SE platform. Any link,guidance is highly appreciated.
Using libraries is the answer? as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947990/sip-programming-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try [asterisk](http://www.asterisk-java.org/development/tutorial.html) though if i understand the question carefully.

good luck :)